# Physical memory location of uninitialised memory location in C program?

Tags: c

I have read that the uninitialized global variables in C will occupy the .bss section of the memory. Also it is just a place holder and doesn't occpy any space in object file.

My question is, once the uninitialised global variable is assigned with some value, where will it will get stored in physical memory?

For example:

```
int a[100];

int main()
{
    a[10] = 25;
}
```

In the above program, where will the memory location be allocated?

Comment: It might be worth noting that C does not have a memory model _at all_.

Answer (score 7):

Where the global variables will be stored is implementation defined, the C standard does not define where it should be saved.
The C Standard does not even mention Bss segment or Data segment it only defines the behavior such variables must show.

Comment: And even then, BSS and data segments are locations in virtual, not physical, memory.

Answer (score 4):

I think your misunderstanding is thinking that BSS is "permanently zero" memory. It's just a section of the program load mapping that's *implicitly zero* and thus avoids having any physical storage on disk, but otherwise it's a standard private writable mapping, and takes on physical existence as soon as it's written to.

If you're thinking about it moving, perhaps you're confusing virtual and physical addresses. The virtual address of an object in C never changes, and the physical address is never visible to you and should never matter.